# How I display comments under the it's post in flutter?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart

I want to display comments under the post in **flutter** ? all posts are loading in a **list view** in the previous page. once click a list user can able to see the full post in next page. but I want to **load its comments under the post**. my database is MongoDB. I used two separate tables posts and comments tables to store data. my current code is

```
`class MyPostsFull extends StatefulWidget {
  List list;
  int index;
  MyPostsFull({this.index, this.list});
  @override
  _MyPostsFullState createState() => _MyPostsFullState();
}

class _MyPostsFullState extends State<MyPostsFull> {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  var _email;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLoginStatus();
    super.initState();
    this.getData();

  }
  checkLoginStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(sharedPreferences.getString("token") == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);

    }

    var token = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
    var payload = Jwt.parseJwt(token);
    print(payload);
    print(payload["email"]);
    _email = payload["email"].toString();
    print(_email);

    setState(() {});
  }
  List data;
  var ip = Configuration.yourIp;
  var apiPort = Configuration.yourApiPort;
  Future<List> getData() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://$ip:$apiPort/comments/$_email");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }


  Future<List> deleteData(String id) async {
    var _id = id;
    var ip = Configuration.yourIp;
    var apiPort = Configuration.yourApiPort;
    final response = await http.delete("http://$ip:$apiPort/posts/$_pid");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }






  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var pid = "${widget.list[widget.index]['_id']}";
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: new AppBar(
         iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.black, // back button color
          ),
         elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: new Center(child:  new Text("${widget.list[widget.index]['title']}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ),)),
      ),
      body: new Container(
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(

        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new Card(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, left: 2),),
               new Image.asset('assets/images/ex.jpg',height: 210,),
               Container(
                  margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 1.0, end: 210.0, top: 10),
                  child: new Text(" Post By: ${widget.list[widget.index]['authortype']}", style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontSize: 11.0, color: Colors.redAccent[200]),),
                ),
                new Text(" \n\n ${widget.list[widget.index]['subject']}", style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0),),
                Container(
                  margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 1.0, end: 1.0, top: 10),
                  child: new Text(" ${widget.list[widget.index]['discription']}", style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontSize: 13.0, color: Colors.brown),),
                ),

                 Container(

                  margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 1.0, end: 1.0, top: 10),
                  child: new  IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
        highlightColor: Colors.pink,
        onPressed: () {
          var _id =  widget.list[widget.index]['_id'];
         deleteData(_id);
      },
      ),

                ),
                   Container(
                  margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 1.0, end: 1.0, top: 10),
                  child: new Text(" ${widget.list[widget.index]['_id']}", style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontSize: 13.0, color: Colors.brown),),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height:10,
                ),
            Container( child:    new FutureBuilder<List>(
               future: getData(),
               builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                 return snapshot.hasData
                     ? new ItemList(
                   list: snapshot.data,
                 )
                     : new Center(
                   child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                 );
               },
             ),
            )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );

  }
}

class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {


  final List list;
  ItemList({this.list});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return new Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => new MyPostsFull (
                    list: list,
                    index: i,
                  )),
            ),
            child: new Card(
              child: new ListTile(
                leading: Image.asset('assets/images/signup.png',height: 110,),
                title: new  RichText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  text: TextSpan(
                      text:  list[i]['title'].toString(),

                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[850], fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "\n \n" + list[i]['subject'].toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.red[600],fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontSize: 13)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "\n Posted On:" + list[i]['date'].toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.red[600],fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontSize: 13)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "\n \nby:\t" + list[i]['authortype'].toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blueAccent[100],fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontSize: 13)),
                      ]),

                ),

              ),

            ),
          ),
        );
      },

    );
  }
}
`
```

In this code display, only the post didn't load comment list.

and also I need to assign postId value to `http://$ip:$apiPort/posts/$_pid");` to $pid variable

Comment: Don't understand your question. You want to display the comments or fetch the data?

Comment: fetch data and display below the post

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to display comments of a post from a List, you may want to consider using [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) on your ListView items or [ExpansionPanelList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html). Then assuming that you have already fetched the data needed to displayed, this can be easily passed to the necessary widgets with an Object.